# Can you send pop-up notifications with an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

What commands of code do I look into to make my app send pop-up notifications even after it is completely terminated (closed)? Where do I place the code (ViewControllerclass or AppDelegate etc...) and what commands should I look into using. If the functionality I am asking for is impossible can some one tell me what to research or what part to look into to get similar functionality, I basically need to make Pop-up notifications that take up the screen and grab the users attention.

Comment: Are you looking for push notification ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for notifications (not your own pop up alerts). You can do push notifications from a remote server (your own or a service like Push.io, Parse etc), or you can use local notifications from the app directly.

Here's a link to get started: https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

Answer (score 0):

This is the detail on the NSAlert class from Apple's documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/

NSHipster also wrote up a post on the topic which you may find helpful.

http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/

Comment: The other thing you'll probably want to read up on is NSNotificationCenter. I've found NSHipster to be a very useful site for explaining various aspects of Swift.

http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't allow to run app in back ground more than 3 min. So if what you want is quite impossible, but i have  seen one option to run app completely in back ground by selection Edit Scheme of your project, and select Back ground fetch from Run section as shown in below image. I have not try to work around as you want, because as per my concern app will not execute after it closed in iOS [image]